# WNDCLASS and Window Handle in Seperate or Same Class?

Tags: c++, windows, oop, winapi

Okay, serious dilemma. I am trying to wrap the Windows API. and the biggest design problem I've run into (for now) is what class is suitable for wrapping what? Since I've created a Windows API wrapper about three times before, always running into a design issue in the middle of things, this time, I intend to tread carefully, asking the confusing parts over here before implementing them.

Should the `WNDCLASS` and the main windows created by `CreateWindow` be wrapped in a *single* class or separate classes? Should I create a singleton to hold the `WNDCLASS`?

Also, if anyone can give me a flow-chart or general idea, on how to abstract the Windows API into classes, some good design tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good source of inspiration, look at the .Net framework - there is no concept of WNDCLASS! You could have your library create a WNDCLASS that is shared by all your windows. You don't need singletons (uurrgghhh) since the class can be used by a string. If you want to change some of the characteristics that WNDCLASS defines for a particular window, I think you can use the SetWindowLongPtr function.

Things to consider:

1. Would there be a need to have multiple WNDCLASS instances?
2. Do you want clients to access the WNDCLASS data?
3. Is there a one-to-one relationship between windows and WNDCLASS or is it one-to-many?

Comment: Hmm, look closer.  There are WNDCLASS, WNDCLASS_I and WNDCLASS_D classes in the framework.  They are internal of course, no point in exposing the plumbing.

Comment: If life were so easy, why, none would suffer in the world! Unfortunately different windows might want different WNDCLASSes under the hood - for example, to have different styles on the window or to register different WndProcs for each window. By having a singleton you force your API to be less generic than Windows actually provides functionality for.

Comment: +1, Nice idea. So you're saying that I should abstract the WNDCLASS completely? But are you sure this won't present any problems?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: Not just abstract it, have no public interface to it at all. Let the window object deal with the nuts and bolts of window handles and WNDCLASS. How you encapsulate the structure is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you are not using ATL?

See the ATL [CWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s420ff40%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as a light weight wrapper around windows:

```
class CMyWindow : public CWindowImpl<CMyWindow>, ...
{
public:
   // Optionally specify name of the new Windows class
   DECLARE_WND_CLASS("MyName") 
              // If this macro is not specified in your
              // class, ATL will generate a class name
   ...

   BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyWindow)
      MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_PAINT, OnPaint)
   END_MSG_MAP()

   LRESULT OnPaint(UINT nMsg, WPARAM wParam, 
                   LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
   {
      // Do some painting code
      return 0;
   }
};
```

Go as heavy or as light-weight as you want with ATL.

Comment: I'm not doing anything important. I just like messing around with the Windows API. This is just an educational project. For real gui programming I generally use GTK or the C# Windows Forms. :D

Answer (score 1):

They should be seperate classes for the simple reason that multiple windows can inherit from the same class.

The way I've done this before is your CWindow class asks a static method of the CWindowClass class to create a window class given specific parameters. The CWindowClass then either registers a new window class, wrapped in a CWindowClass to return to the caller, or it recycles an existing one to return to the caller by caching previous successful classes.

Your CWindow class can then set about creating a window handle using the underlying name of the registered class, and when the CWindow is disposed it can decrement the reference count on the CWindowClass - the last dereference of which will release the class properly.